# Maxima: cummulatively apply function to a list's atoms

Tags: list, maxima

is there a way to apply a function cumulatively to each atom of a list ? For instance :

```
wishedFunction("+",[1,2,4,7,3])
```

Would compute `(((1+2)+4)+7)+3` and hence return `17`

In other words I am looking for a maxima equivalent to the [python `reduce()` function](http://www.lleess.com/2013/07/python-built-in-function-map-reduce-zip.html).

I have read the documentation for the `map()` and `scanmap()` functions, but they do not behave the same way…

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually what you are looking for is indeed one of the built-in `reduce` functions (`lreduce`, `rreduce`, `xreduce`, `tree_reduce`).

```
(%i1) xreduce ("+", [1,2,4,7,3]);
(%o1)                                 17
```

Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I was thinking that you want a function which returns a list with the accumulating partial results. Obviously that's incorrect. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `lreduce` and friends (`rreduce`, `xreduce`, `tree_reduce`) don't act the way you want. I don't know a function that does that; maybe you can enter a feature request for it. See: https://sourceforge.net/p/maxima/feature-requests/

Here's a function to do that. Disclaimer: I didn't think about it too much.

```
(%i41) foo (f, L) := 
         block ([x0 : first (L)],
         cons (first (L),
               makelist (x0 : f(x0, x), x, rest (L)))) $
(%i42) foo (g, [1,2,3,4]);
(%o42)         [1, g(1, 2), g(g(1, 2), 3), g(g(g(1, 2), 3), 4)]
(%i43) foo ("+", [1,2,3,4]);
(%o43)                           [1, 3, 6, 10]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer : I just added a ticket on sourceforge as you suggested.